# How do I set --icc=true in docker-machine?

Tags: docker-machine

[Best security practice](http://container-solutions.com/content/uploads/2015/06/15.06.15_DockerCheatSheet_A2.pdf) for docker is to set `--icc=false` and `--iptables` in the docker daemon. How can I make these settings in docker-machine on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docker-machine ssh default "echo $'EXTRA_ARGS=\"--icc=false\"' | sudo tee -a /var/lib/boot2docker/profile && sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart"
```

Basically ssh into the docker machine, update the `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` and restart docker